# UILabel in UICollectionViewCell is nill

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uicollectionviewcell

I have added a UILabel on the UICollectionViewCell through the xib.
I have made the necessary objects in the class and connected it appropriately.
In the cellForItemAtIndexPath method i get access to the UILabel declared but the label is always nill.
I can add background color to the Cell programmatically but not via the Xib. I can also add the label programmatically and work with it.
But i cant do anything with the label via the xib.
I have registered the Cell class and the nib.
Would be great if someone could help me out with this issue

the code snippet inside cellforitem-

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
VideoCellCollection *cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
[cell clearData];
VideoInfo *video=[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
cell.lblName.text=video.strFileName; 

return cell
```

Code inside viewdidload

```
UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"VideoCellCollection" bundle:nil];

[self.collectionView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
[self.collectionView registerClass:[VideoCellCollection class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Please post some code for cellForItemAtIndexPath ?

Comment: Can you post some for We get some idea.And one more thing are you using tag thru get the reference of label?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `[self.collectionView registerClass:[VideoCellCollection class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];`

Comment: Tried it before . Doesnt work. i know this should work. but it is really strange.